# What can you infer from being always above the median and the mean?

Tags: inference, mean, median

In the context of a national competition, what can you infer from being always above the median and the mean in all modules? Say, that all marks are normally distributed, does it always mean that for a final mark being calculated with equal weights for each module, you are in the first half or not? Could it be possible to infer more information about it?

I thought about modeling the situation as $n$ (the number of modules, i.e. the number of marks) Bernoulli experiences with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$: it's a success if your mark is higher than the median (which is equal to the mean as we may consider normal distribution for example). Then we could represent the global situation using a tree with $n$ steps, and having always a mark greater than the median would lead to one and only path of all success among $2^n$ paths. Then, it would mean that only $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (in proportion) people are in the same situation. But this looks not "sufficient" to me, as we could also say that the same proportion of people have done the opposite and have been always below the median. Moreover, someone could have been just below the median for $n-1$ modules and get a very high mark for the last module.

How could we improve this model, as its main weakness is that it does not take into account the actual marks. Assume we know all the medians (=means) for each module, would there be a different approach (likelihood-based maybe) to infer if we are in the top $x\%$ on the global/final mark?

Comment: It would help to have a clear description of "marks" and "modules" and how everything is combined to determine "in the first half."  Are "marks" *independent* from one "module" to the next or not?  It's hard to justify your deduction that "only $1/2^n$" of people can have above-median marks.  Mathematically, up to half of everyone can be in this situation and there are probability models for which the proportion could be anywhere between $0$ and $1/2.$  What we most need is for you to provide a clearer model of how all marks are generated.